# Unable to mount /efs partition on Samsung Galaxy GT-S7582 & a few more

Tags: android, adb, samsung-mobile

A few weeks ago i was installing a custom rom to my GT-S7582 using TWRP's built in ADB Sideload feature, in the middle of the process i realised that i forgot to wipe cache and a few other necessary partitions, i thought nothing would happen, but i was wrong.
It randomly crashed, and the Lineage OS i flashed before, was not booting.
Now only TWRP and download mode work.

I have another issues :(

- Wiping certain things in TWRP generally just crashes the phone
- Trying to Repair through -> Wipe -> Advanced Wipe -> *Select partition* & Repair / Change FS
- Fix contexts which is Advanced -> Fix Contexts

There are a few more issues, but i dont want to make this even longer than it already is.

Device Specifications:
Model NUM : GT-S7582 from samsung
No external storage eg. sd card
TWRP V. (the one on top, with the battery, time) 3.0-2-0

After 3 weeks of staying in the drawer, I pulled it out and tried to flash Stock ROM via odin which didnt work. So i tried with a custom rom which didnt work and spit an error like :

"Unable to mount /efs (Invalid arguments)
Unable to mount /system (Invalid arguments)
Unable to mount /cache (invalid arguments)"

So, I went on YouTube and tried solving the error. which most of the steps worked for me except the mounting part which is this command :

## mount -o rw -t EXT4 /dev/block/mmcblk0p15 /efs

## mount: mounting /dev/block/mmcblk0p15 on /efs failed: No such device

The device is recognised by my PC and i can use adb just fine on it but why does it spit this error?? and how do i fix it???

Can anyone help me solve this error.